# How to convert YOLOv4 Darknet Weights to Tensorflow format if you trained with custom anchors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensor, yolo

**Main Question:**

*What changes should I do to the repo's source code to successfully convert my YOLOv4 darknet weight (with custom anchors) to Tensorflow format?*

**Background:**

I used [this repo](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite) to convert my YOLOv4 darknet weights to Tensorflow format.

I have trained YOLOv4 on a **custom dataset** using **custom anchors** (9 anchors) but the number of anchors I used per [yolo] layer is 4, 3, 2, respectively. By default, YOLOv4 uses 3 anchors each [yolo] layer.

**Main Problem:**

The repo I used is coded in a way that only considers the default anchors, where there are [3 anchors each [yolo] layer](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite/blob/9f16748aa3f45ff240608da4bd9b1216a29127f5/core/config.py#L22).

**What I tried to do to solve the main problem:**

- I have tried to do some changes to the source code, which are
  summarized in this [link](https://pastebin.com/XkSzzvYJ).
- I used the code below to attempt converting the darknet weight to tf format. Here is the [log](https://pastebin.com/raw/ecHSkcLt) of the conversion
  process.

`python save_model.py --weights data/yolov4-512.weights --output ./checkpoints/yolov4-512 --input_size 512 --model yolov4`

- I tested the resulting tf model using the code: `python detect.py --weights checkpoints/yolov4-512 --size 512 --model yolov4 --image data/pear.jpg` . The process **failed** and the error can be seen below. I have seen possible problems [here](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite/blob/master/core/dataset.py#L330-L370) but I don't know how to solve them.

```
2021-03-19 15:05:03.694379: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:312] Garbage collection: deallocate free memory regions (i.e., allocations) so that we can re-allocate a larger region to avoid OOM due to memory fragmentation. If you see this message frequently, you are running near the threshold of the available device memory and re-allocation may incur great performance overhead. You may try smaller batch sizes to observe the performance impact. Set TF_ENABLE_GPU_GARBAGE_COLLECTION=false if you'd like to disable this feature.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "detect.py", line 90, in <module>
        app.run(main)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
        _run_main(main, args)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
        sys.exit(main(argv))
      File "detect.py", line 66, in main
        pred_bbox = infer(batch_data)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1655, in __call__
        return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1673, in _call_impl
        return self._call_with_flat_signature(args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1722, in _call_with_flat_signature
        return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 106, in _call_flat
        cancellation_manager)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1924, in _call_flat
        ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 550, in call
        ctx=ctx)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
        inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 98304 values, but the requested shape has 73728
             [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/functional_1/tf_op_layer_Reshape/Reshape}}]] [Op:__inference_signature_wrapper_5589]
    
    Function call stack:
    signature_wrapper
```

Comment: Have you tried [MMdnn](https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn)?

Comment: Looks like they [only support yolov2 and v3](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn/blob/master/mmdnn/conversion/darknet/README.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted an answer to one of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705733/how-to-convert-yolov4-csp-darknet-weight-to-tensorflow-format) about YoloV4 (CSP) conversion. Did you try and see if that worked?

If that worked, you can try to use your own config file and weights in the `convert.py` command in the notebook and see if it works