# How to convert YOLOv4-CSP darknet weight to Tensorflow format?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, yolo, darknet

How to convert YOLOv4-CSP darknet weights to Tensorflow (tf) format?

I have tried using this [repo](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite) but it didn't work.

I had this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "save_model.py", line 58, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "save_model.py", line 54, in main
    save_tf()
  File "save_model.py", line 49, in save_tf
    utils.load_weights(model, FLAGS.weights, FLAGS.model, FLAGS.tiny)
  File "D:\swap\20210319\tensorflow-yolov4-tflite\core\utils.py", line 63, in load_weights
    conv_weights = conv_weights.reshape(conv_shape).transpose([2, 3, 1, 0])
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3791890 into shape (1024,512,3,3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repository that you are using doesn't support conversion of Scaled YoloV4 or Yolov4-csp yet. It's still a feature request according to [this](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite/issues/280) issue

There's luckily a workaround. I found [this](https://github.com/david8862/keras-YOLOv3-model-set) repository that does the same thing, only difference being it converts the model to `.h5` (keras format) before converting into tensorflow format. This also supports `yolov4-csp`.

I made a Google Colab notebook that does the conversion, which can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/122fHTJ8RZ4CD0z79NaoyjhYllqOwpen6?usp=sharing).

Comment: I am working on same thing. Can I get something for the Pytorch version too?

Comment: I haven't tested it out, but you can try [this](https://github.com/AceCoooool/YOLO-pytorch)

Comment: i want to convert yolo-csp,yolo-mish weight into pytorchweight i.e .pth

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi I tried to run your Colab notebook but ran into a few errors. See: https://github.com/david8862/keras-YOLOv3-model-set/issues/244 

Can you confirm your Colab notebook still works?